# Plotting two curves on one graph

Tags: python, dictionary, plot

I am trying to make a plot. On x-axis, I wanna see the keys of my `FinalSigmaValues` dictionary and on y-axis I wanna see the values of the same dictionary. I want them to create a smooth curve. Meanwhile, I have another dictionary which has the same keys as `FinalSigmaValues`. So, I also want another curve on the same plot. I am using the following code and getting lots of errors.

```
from scipy.interpolate import spline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import collections
Finalsigma = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(FinalSigmaValues.items()))
P = np.array(Finalsigma.keys())
T = np.array(Finalsigma.values())
xnew = np.linspace(T.min(),T.max(),300)
P_smooth = spline(T,P,xnew)
plt.plot(xnew,P_smooth,color='k')
plt.xlabel('w')
plt.ylabel('First Part of the Objective Function')
plt.show()
```

As you see in the code, I am currently only trying to plot `FinalSigmaValues`, I also have 'FinalPhiValues' to worry about. Both dictionaries are in len 1376. Any suggestions appreciated.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-2d2343ec9634> in <module>()
      4 xnew = np.linspace(T.min(),T.max(),300) 
      5 
----> 6 P_smooth = spline(T,P,xnew)
      7 
      8 plt.plot(xnew,P_smooth,color='k')

C:\Users\administrater\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.pyc in spline(xk, yk, xnew, order, kind, conds)
   3010 
   3011     """
-> 3012     return spleval(splmake(xk,yk,order=order,kind=kind,conds=conds),xnew)

C:\Users\administrater\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.pyc in splmake(xk, yk, order, kind, conds)
   2925     # the constraint matrix
   2926     B = _fitpack._bsplmat(order, xk)
-> 2927     coefs = func(xk, yk, order, conds, B)
   2928     return xk, coefs, order
   2929 

C:\Users\administrater\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.pyc in _find_smoothest(xk, yk, order, conds, B)
   2622     tmp = dot(V2.T,A)
   2623     Q = dot(tmp,V2)
-> 2624     p = scipy.linalg.solve(Q, tmp)
   2625     tmp = dot(V2,p)
   2626     tmp = np.eye(N+K) - tmp

C:\Users\administrater\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.pyc in solve(a, b, sym_pos, lower, overwrite_a, overwrite_b, debug, check_finite)
    101         return x
    102     if info > 0:
--> 103         raise LinAlgError("singular matrix")
    104     raise ValueError('illegal value in %d-th argument of internal gesv|posv' %
    105                      -info)

LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

Alternatively, I tried:

```
from scipy.interpolate import spline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import collections
Finalsigma = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(FinalSigmaValues.items()))
Finalphi = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(FinalPhiValues.items()))

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = Finalsigma.keys()
y = Finalsigma.values()
f = interp1d(x, y)
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

xnew = Finalphi.values()
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, f(xnew), '-', xnew, f2(xnew), '--')
plt.show()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-51a1312588ca> in <module>()
     14 
     15 xnew = Finalphi.values()
---> 16 plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, f(xnew), '-', xnew, f2(xnew), '--')
     17 plt.show()

C:\Users\administrater\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\polyint.pyc in __call__(self, x)
     77         """
     78         x, x_shape = self._prepare_x(x)
---> 79         y = self._evaluate(x)
     80         return self._finish_y(y, x_shape)
     81 

C:\Users\administrater\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.pyc in _evaluate(self, x_new)
    586         y_new = self._call(self, x_new)
    587         if not self._extrapolate:
--> 588             below_bounds, above_bounds = self._check_bounds(x_new)
    589             if len(y_new) > 0:
    590                 # Note fill_value must be broadcast up to the proper size

C:\Users\administrater\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.pyc in _check_bounds(self, x_new)
    618                 "range.")
    619         if self.bounds_error and above_bounds.any():
--> 620             raise ValueError("A value in x_new is above the interpolation "
    621                 "range.")
    622 

ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.
```

Comment: "Getting lots of errors" is not descriptive enough. Please provide the exact error messages. Don't forget to format them as code.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. Now, it is added.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try something like below (code picked up from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html)

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=11, endpoint=True)
y = np.cos(-x**2/9.0)
f = interp1d(x, y)
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

xnew = np.linspace(0, 10, num=41, endpoint=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, f(xnew), '-', xnew, f2(xnew), '--')
plt.legend(['data', 'linear', 'cubic'], loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Couldn't really understand how to use it. Please take a look how I tried to use it above. It still gives an error.